# clickhouse - CollapsingMergeTree works like ReplacingMergeTree

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I created docker container with clickhouse-server inside with mounted directory.

```
docker run -d --name clickserver -p 8213:8123 -v C:\Users\mankov.k\Desktop\Test_task\epay:/data chserver
```

chserver is a docker image created via Dockerfile

```
FROM clickhouse/clickhouse-server:21.11.6.7
WORKDIR /data

docker build -t chtest8 .
```

Now I have a csv file called data.csv and I am trying to isert it inside CollapsingMergeTree table.

The table created by calling

```
CREATE TABLE cmt_1(id UInt64, 
                   dt_u DateTime, 
                   IdUser UInt32, 
                   Summa Decimal(11, 2), 
                   agent UInt16, 
                   idCurrency UInt16, 
                   subagent UInt32, 
                   dt_pay DateTime, 
                   mainUserId UInt32, 
                   id_country UInt16, 
                   refUser UInt16, 
                   refTransact UInt32, 
                   globalProject UInt16, 
                   currencyUser UInt16, 
                   AffilateId UInt32, 
                   isFirstdep UInt8, 
                   epay_status UInt32, 
                   Sign Int8)Engine=CollapsingMergeTree(Sign) 
ORDER BY (epay_status, agent, subagent) 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(dt_pay);
```

Inside data.csv there are 132 million rows and field Sign in every row equals to 1 (I mean that there isn't any -1 in Sign field)

I am tryind to insert data using bash comand

```
cat data.csv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO cmt_1 FORMAT CSV"
```

Everyting inserts fine except my CollapsingMergeTree works like ReplacingMergeTree one. I mean that it deletes rows with equal values from ORDER BY fields (epay_status, agent, subagent). But CollapsingMergeTree should delete rows with equal ORDER BY fields **and** diffenent Sign values (-1 and 1). But I don't have any -1 in Sign field.

As a result my 130 million rows collapse into 65k rows.

Example

in csv I have

```
922514853,"2019-04-05 15:28:37",56091623,10,58,12,1171,"2020-11-20 13:50:58",56091623,148,1,0,1,12,0,0,3,1
1217950451,"2019-08-26 11:26:40",5237207,15,490,20,2579,"2020-11-26 15:16:21",5237207,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,5,1
1217958553,"2019-08-26 11:26:40",5237207,2,490,20,2579,"2020-11-26 15:16:21",5237207,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,7,1
1217975479,"2019-08-26 11:26:40",5237207,2,490,20,2579,"2020-11-26 15:16:21",5237207,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2,1
1217975675,"2019-08-26 11:26:40",5237207,2,490,12,2579,"2020-11-26 16:07:07",5237207,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,7,1
```

But in my table I have

```
┌─────────id─┬────────────────dt_u─┬────IdUser─┬─Summa─┬─agent─┬─idCurrency─┬─subagent─┬──────────────dt_pay─┬─mainUserId─┬─id_country─┬─refUser─┬─refTransact─┬─globalProject─┬─currencyUser─┬─AffilateId─┬─isFirstdep─┬─epay_status─┬─Sign─┐
│ 1217950451 │ 2019-08-26 11:26:40 │   5237207 │    15 │   490 │         20 │     2579 │ 2020-11-26 15:16:21 │    5237207 │          1 │       1 │           0 │             1 │            1 │          0 │          0 │           5 │    1 │
│ 1217975479 │ 2019-08-26 11:26:40 │   5237207 │     2 │   490 │         20 │     2579 │ 2020-11-26 15:16:21 │    5237207 │          1 │       1 │           0 │             1 │            1 │          0 │          0 │           2 │    1 │
│ 1217975675 │ 2019-08-26 11:26:40 │   5237207 │     2 │   490 │         12 │     2579 │ 2020-11-26 16:07:07 │    5237207 │          1 │       1 │           0 │             1 │            1 │          0 │          0 │           7 │    1 │
│ 1222374915 │ 2019-08-26 11:26:40 │   5237207 │    50 │   490 │         12 │     2597 │ 2020-11-26 16:07:07 │    5237207 │          1 │       1 │           0 │             1 │            1 │          0 │          0 │           4 │    1 │
│ 1629063475 │ 2020-01-09 18:12:46 │ 160644195 │    25 │   111 │          3 │     2045 │ 2020-11-04 11:57:50 │  160644195 │          2 │      25 │           0 │             1 │            3 │          0 │          0 │           1 │    1 │
```

You can see that rows with `id` 1217958553 and 1217975675 collapsed into the second one.

What am I doing whong, guys?

Comment: Could you please provide example of `data.csv` with 2 rows whice are collapsed into 1 row?

Comment: @AndreiKoch added to the description of the problem

Comment: Are you sure about this? You've posted just snippet of the table. Also you have 5 rows here both in csv and in a table. I would recommend you to narrow down the problem by creating separate table with the same structure and inserting exactly 5 specified rows

Comment: @AndreiKoch I sorted rows by id in both csv and table so I can check if there is anything different between at least first 5 rows.

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/collapsingmergetree/  The last “state” row, if there are more “state” rows than “cancel” rows.

Comment: @DennyCrane oh, now I see why this is happening. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DennyCrane for his answer in the comments.

[CollapsingMergetree documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/collapsingmergetree/)

CollapsingMergeTree basically collapses rows with same values in ORDER BY fields, that is the feature. Also, you must know, that I doesn't collapse everything at the same time, collapsing process might take a while, so you can use OPTIMIZE TABLE <table_name> FINISH; to collapse everything without waiting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).